# How to set absolute path for docker volume in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a quite simple `docker-compose.yml` that creates an initial volume for a `mysql` container:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
   
volumes:
  database:
    name: mysql-database
```

Question: how can I tell docker to create the volume on a specific absolute path on first startup, instead of creating it at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/mysql-database/`?

I would like to set the target path to `/mnt/docker/volumes/mysql-database/` for having it on another disk. But only this volume, not all docker volumes!

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

With the `local` volume driver comes the ability to use arbitrary mounts; by using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) you can achieve exactly this.

For setting up a named volume that gets mounted into `/mnt/docker/volumes/mysql-database`, your docker-compose.yml would look like this:

```
volumes:
  database:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/mnt/docker/volumes/mysql-database'
```

By using a bind mount you lose in flexibility since it's harder to reuse the same volume. But you don't lose anything in regards of functionality

Comment: Is your `volumes:` definition the same as simply using `volumes: - /mnt/docker/volumes/mysql-database:/var/lib/mysql` directly in the service definition without global volumes definitions?

Comment: The difference is, that with this way you have the ability to tackle more complex cases since you can define more attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not use the volumes section since you don't know where docker puts your data.

So, specify the full path. It does work for our installation.
Interested to know when this does not work for your situation.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - /mnt/docker/volumes/mysql-database:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Is there any advantage/disadvantage in using direct bind mounts instead of named volumes?

Comment: I have not yet found a disadvantage. The big advantage is (opinion!!) that you know where your data is. But this comes from running docker on OSX which puts docker volumes somewhere which nobody can find. :-)

Comment: Bind mounts can be distinctly slower on MacOS (this will be true of manually setting up a bind mount in a named volume as well).  I feel like permissions are a little easier to manage in named volumes.  If you use on the Docker misfeature of copying image content into a volume, it only happens with named volumes.  But otherwise, "I know where the files are" is a huge advantage to bind mounts.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to create a "named bind mount", having the advantage that `docker volume ls` will still show the volume, even it is a bindmount:

Create:
`docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=/mnt/docker/volumes/mysql-database --opt o=bind mysql-database`

Usage:

```
volumes:
  database:
    name: mysql-database
    external: true
```